# HuggingChat API?

Tags: python, chatbot, huggingface

I am trying to access HuggingChat using requests in Python but I am getting a response code of 500 for some reason. What I have so far is something like this:

```
hf_url = "https://huggingface.co/chat"
resp = session.post(hf_url + f"/conversation/{self.now_conversation}", json=req_json, stream=True)
```

The JSON objects holds the "inputs" field and other "parameters" such as temperature, top_p, etc.

```
req_json = {
            "inputs": text,
            "parameters": {
                "temperature": temperature,
                "top_p": top_p,
...
```

Is there no API I can directly use? If not, is there a auth I am missing here? I inspected the request going from my browser when I chat with HuggingChat and didn't really find anything.

Comment: If it can help you, there is an unofficial implementation https://github.com/Soulter/hugging-chat-api

Comment: @VICTORRODEÑOSANCHEZ it doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qaFO02esnDE4ljCXXArbZav1TRDQA4Qt?usp=sharing

Comment: Doesn't work on my local setup. But thank you for the notebook!

Comment: I believe you have to pass your auth cookies to use this endpoint

Answer (score 0):

```
from hugchat import hugchat
from hugchat.login import Login

sign = Login("dishant.sardhara@shreecode.com", "Dishant@2101")
cookies = sign.login()
sign.saveCookiesToDir()

chatbot = hugchat.ChatBot(cookies=cookies.get_dict()) 
id = chatbot.new_conversation()
chatbot.change_conversation(id)

print('[[ Welcome to AI. Let\'s talk! ]]')
print('\'q\' or \'quit\' to exit')
print('\'c\' or \'change\' to change conversation')
print('\'n\' or \'new\' to start a new conversation')

while True:
    user_input = input('> ')
    if user_input.lower() == '':
        pass
    elif user_input.lower() in ['q', 'quit']:
        break
    elif user_input.lower() in ['c', 'change']:
        print('Choose a conversation to switch to:')
        print(chatbot.get_conversation_list())
    elif user_input.lower() in ['n', 'new']:
        print('Clean slate!')
        id = chatbot.new_conversation()
        chatbot.change_conversation(id)
    else:
        print(chatbot.chat(user_input))
```

try this..

Comment: Add some explanation so that your changes can be understood clearly.